# SQL Query seems to multiply results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query to display how many times a person has been a referee and an assistant referee in matches.

However it seems to be multiplying the ref number by the AR number, so if it should be 11 & 6, it says 66 & 66.  I can't see why?  (And it's probably very obvious to experienced coders):

```
SELECT CONCAT (lastname,', ',firstname),
    A.gender,
    DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%d %b %y'),
    DATE_FORMAT(dod, '%d %b %y'),
    CASE 
        WHEN NOT dod = '0000-00-00'
            THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, dob, dod)
        ELSE TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, dob, Curdate())
        END,
    B.NAME,
    COUNT(M.REF),
    COUNT(M1.AR1),
    refID
FROM refs A
    LEFT JOIN teams B
        ON A.Nationality = B.TeamID
    LEFT JOIN matches M
        ON A.refID = M.REF
    LEFT JOIN matches M1
        ON A.refID = M1.AR1
GROUP BY A.refID
ORDER BY lastname;
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Your left joins are probably causing the issue.

Comment: It bothers me a lot that MySql let's you do this group by thing where it breaks the query.

Comment: If I knew what you were trying to do I might even be able to fix your query

Comment: Should really the Nationality from table refs be joined on the TeamID from table Teams. I.e. should they really have the same value?

Comment: It would be helpful to see sample data on this one...

Comment: use `distinct` in `count(distinct m.ref)`...etc.

Comment: Sample data can be seen here: http://www.rugbyrefs.com/TMDB/DisplayRefs.php

The nationality can use the team ID as this is for international matches, so that works for what I am doing.

Comment: Tried distinct, but it shanges the answers to 1 and 1 regardless of games involved in.

Comment: TheMayer, I have a DB of rugby matches, the list the referees and assistant referees, with this code I am trying to show how many games a person has 1, refereed, 2, assistant refereed and if you look at the sample data it is also looking at TV Ref.

I broke them down to see that when I put Ref & AR together, it multiplies them, but I can't see why, and don't know how to fix it.  Hope that helps explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: @JacobH Thankfully in MySQL 5.7 the vanilla install defaults to erroring out when a GROUP BY does not contain all of the non-aggregated columns like every other RDBMS. This feature can be toggled off to act like older versions, but it's a step in the right direction. It leads so many people (like OP) towards oddball hard-to-explain results.

Comment: Perfect help, thanks guys, distinct & using the primary key gave the right results.